# BST null pointer assignment error

Tags: c, runtime-error, binary-search-tree, null-pointer

I tried implementing the BST program but the execution failed because of a runtime error. Please tell me how to correct it. My code for creation of the tree is:

```
struct node *createBinTree()
{ int val,size;
   struct node *bintree, *newnode;
   bintree= NULL;
   printf("Enter the values of nodes terminated by a negetive no.\n");
   val=0;
   while(val>=0)
   {
     printf("\nEnter value");
     scanf("%d",&val);
     if(val>=0)
     { newnode = (struct node*)sizeof(struct node);
    newnode->val=val;
    newnode->lchild= NULL;
    newnode->rchild= NULL;
    bintree=attach(bintree,newnode);
     }
   }
   return bintree;
   }
   struct node *attach(struct node *tree,struct node* tnode)
   {if(tree==NULL)
     tree=tnode;
     else{
     if(tnode->val<tree->val)
      tree->lchild= attach(tree->lchild,tnode);
      else
      tree->rchild= attach(tree->rchild,tnode);

   }
   return tree;
  }
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do? `newnode = (struct node*)sizeof(struct node);`

Comment: If you haven't used a debugger yet now is the perfect time for it. Running your program in a debugger will help you find the location of the crash, as well as let you see the call stack so you know how it ended up at that location, and also let you examine variables to help you figure what might have caused the crash.

Comment: Please let us know what is the error! Use the "edit" link at the end of your post and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

```
newnode = (struct node*)sizeof(struct node);
```

This is not how you would create a node. Either you aren't using `malloc` or forgot to include it in your code here. Instead you're assigning it an address directly, which is never recommended. Change this to use `malloc` and you should be fine.

Comment: Oh yea I forgot to include it. Thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
newnode = (struct node*)sizeof(struct node);
```

You are missing `malloc()` in this above line in while loop

use this :

```
newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```